# PDF File cannot be opened in new tab HTML

Tags: html, pdf

I want to open pdf file on new tab, but why my code open new tab and download its file?

```
<a href="assets/readme.pdf" target="_blank">Read Me</a>
```

Comment: <a href="assets/readme.pdf" target="_blank">Read Me</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, there is a chrome setting you have to disable:

[image]

chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments

Comment: i can't open you sharelink

Comment: chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments

Comment: I just see button on off with text "Download PDF files without automatically opening them in Chrome"